# Self-adjoint extensions of symmetric linear differential operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Are they general techniques to determine the sef-adjoint extensions of
a  symmetric linear differential operators in 2 variables with (real) variable
coefficients? Any suggestions for references? Typically I am interested in
studying the self-adjoint extensions of differential operators of the form:
$$
L= a(x,y) \partial_{xx} + b(x,y) \partial_{yy} + c(x,y) \partial_x + d(x,y) \partial_y
$$
on an open set $U=\{(x,y)\mid x,y>0\}$, the coefficents are real smooth functions and $L$ is symmetric on the domain $C^\infty_c(U)$ 
for a positive measure $\omega(x,y) dx dy$.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it bounded below?

Comment: L depends on several parameters, and  it is possible to choose these parameters so that L is positive, hence bounded below.

Comment: I would suggest you try Google searches with terms something like [{self-adjoint   partial "second order"  differential  "variable coefficients"}](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=self-adjoint+++partial+%22second+order%22++differential++%22variable+coefficients%22). You might have a better chance of getting an Answer if you could give some motivation (eg. , is it a physics problem? ) and indicate your level of knowledge of PDEs and operator theory.

Comment: Thank you Keith for these remarks. I could already find some material.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to allow all kinds of coefficients and regions, then the problem is far too large. Typically only the uniformly elliptic ones on bounded regions are going to give you something that can be handled.

von Neumann's theory of symmetric operators is classic. All symmetric operators are closable because of the symmetry relation, and this theory tells you why something is not selfadjoint. If $L$ is such an operator that is densely-defined,
$$
                  \mathcal{D}(L^{\star})=\mathcal{D}(L)\oplus\mathcal{N}(L^{\star}-iI)\oplus\mathcal{N}(L^{\star}+iI).  \;\;\; (*)
$$
The selfadjoint extensions of $L$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the unitary maps between $\mathcal{N}(L^{\star}-iI)$ and $\mathcal{N}(L^{\star}+iI)$. This is because a selfadjoint extension $A$ of $L$ gives a unitary map $(A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1}$, and must be such a map. Do there exist such maps? Not in general, but if the operator is real, then complex conjugation will map elements of one deficiency space to the other, and you can then map an orthonormal basis of one onto an orthonormal basis of the other, and extend linearly to a unitary map, thus giving a selfadjoint extension.

A selfadjoint extension of $L$ is a selfadjoint restriction of $L^{\star}$, which can be obtained in practical terms by imposing orthogonality conditions on
$$
    \mathcal{N}((L^{\star})^2+I) = 
 \mathcal{N}(L^{\star}+iI)\oplus\mathcal{N}(L^{\star}-iI).
$$
That's a natural way to reduce the domain of $L^{\star}$. As you do this, the domain of the adjoint of this restriction grows because of the decomposition (*) The goal is to meet in the middle where the two operators are the same. You can work out how to extend $L$ by an element and keep the extension symmetric; von Neumann did that. You end up imposing a restriction on the domain of the form
$$
                (L^{\star}f,g)-(f,L^{\star}g) = 0.
$$
Once you have restricted to elliptic operators, for example, adjoint identities for differential operators will show you that the above condition is a boundary condition. Of course this cannot be done in a haphazard way because random sets of conditions don't lead to a selfadjoint operator. You have to study von Neumann's methods for construction selfadjoint extensions and the unitary maps mentioned before.

Allowing anything other than uniform elliptic is going to be hard because you would potentially have to impose some non-trivial condition in the middle of the domain, which would be ugly, even if you only allow isolated points where the determinant of the elliptic coefficient matrix vanishes. Singular points are very difficult to deal with in general, even for ODEs. That's why such PDE studies are inevitably restricted to uniform elliptic operators on finite domains, or to a few special cases such as free space where the only singularity is at $\infty$. Good luck! These are fascinating problems.

Comment: Thank you TrialAndError for your detailed answer. I will try to learn more on von Neumann's theory. The computation involved here seems to use the adjoint operator. Am I wrong if I say that $L^*$ here is simply the differential operator $L$ acting on the domain of square-integrable functions $f$ (for the measure $\omega(x,y)dxdy$, such that $L(f)$ is also square-integrable?

Comment: @Rodrigo : The adjoint will only require weak derivatives because the adjoint relation is a weak relation.

Comment: If I understand well the domain of the adjoint $L^*$ would be the  set of functions $f$ in the Sobolev space $H^2(\Omega)$ such that $L(f)$ is square-integrable.